# Advanced FTP Logging

Tags: centos, ftp

I have a CentOS server that I would like to be able to track more FTP information, to know the IP/Geolocation/Files Edited, for the last 20 connections. We have cpanel running, also. What can I do to enable advanced FTP logging?

Comment: Do you already have an ftp daemon running?  Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be probably running pure-ftpd (default for cPanel). In this case, you can enable verbose logging for FTP by setting "**VerboseLog yes**" in /etc/pure-ftpd.conf . There is also the "**AltLog**" directive, which you may need to uncomment and enable. There are 3 formats supported, which are **xferlog, stats & w3c** of which you can choose a suitable on.

Comment: Where do the logs end up?

Comment: You define the log path in "AltLog" directive itself along with the preferred format.